# Translation of Lines 333–336 of Vergil's Aeneid Book 4

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, aeneis, vergilius

> Tandem pauca refert: "Ego te, quae plurima fando
>   enumerare vales, numquam, regina, negabo
>   promeritam, nec me meminisse pigebit Elissae
>   dum memor ipse mei, dum spiritus hos regit artus. (4:333–336)

I have come up with two translations for this passage, but I'm not sure which is better/more accurate. They are both a little rough in terms of overall flow.

Version 1: *Finally he carries back such things: "I, queen, never will refuse you having deserved many things which you are strong to recount, nor will it displease Dido to remember me when I am mindful of me, when my spirit directs these bodies.*

Version 2: *At last he brings back a few words: "I will not deny, never, that you have deserved the many things which you are able to enumerate by speaking, nor will it displease me to remember Elissa while I myself and mindful of myself, while my spirit rules these limbs.*

I would greatly appreciate any insight on these translations, or a more correct version if anyone knows a better one!

Answer (score 7):

Your second translation is pretty close to the mark. Let's go through the translation step by step.

Let us first recall to mind the context: Dido has just finished a long harangue (4:305-330) excoriating Aeneas for attempting to leave her in secret. Aeneas is grieved and silent, and then...

> Tandem pauca refert
>
> **At last he spoke these few words**

Although you are right that [*refero*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Drefero) literally means "bring back", it has a poetic meaning in this context: "to say in return, to rejoin, answer, reply (syn. respondeo)." In fact, this is one of the example passages for this meaning quoted in the L&S entry!

> Ego te, quae plurima fando enumerare vales, numquam, regina, negabo promeritam
>
> **I will never deny that you, o queen, are deserving of those things which you are able to detail in your long speech.**

This is tricky: [*promeritam*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dpromereor) means to "deserve, be worthy" and, as seen in the entry for [*mereo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=mereor&la=la&can=mereor0&prior=pr%C5%8D&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=promereor&i=1#lexicon), can take the accusative. It is likely an echo of a previous line from Dido's speech:

> si bene quid de te merui... (4:317)

What is she worthy of? The answer is in a relative clause: *[omnia] quae enumerate vales* ("everything which you are able to enumerate") *plurima fando* (lit. "by saying many things" = "in your long speech").

> nec me meminisse pigebit Elissae dum memor ipse mei, dum spiritus hos regit artus.
>
> **nor will I ever tire of remembering Elissa as long as I am mindful of my own self, as long as my spirit governs these limbs.**

[*piget*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=p%C4%ADget&la=la&can=p%C4%ADget0&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=piget&i=1#lexicon) is used as an impersonal verb: "it will not burden/trouble me..." *Elissae* is in the genitive, since it is the object of *memini*, and poetically refers to Dido in the third person.

The *dum* clauses are poetic ways of saying *dum vivo*, "as long as I live." The point is that Aeneas will sooner forget himself or die rather than forget her.

Comment: Just to clarify, where would "regina" (*queen*) go in the translation?

Comment: @Sapphira Added: it's vocative, addressed to Dido. It's interesting how he changes from 2nd to 3rd person in the middle of his "short" speech!

Answer (score 5):

You might enjoy Dryden's famous — but magnificently erratic — translation, completed in 1697 :

*. . . and thus at length replies, / "Fair Queen, you never can enough repeat / Your boundless favours, or I own my debt, / Nor can my mind forget Eliza's* (!) *name, / While vital breath inspires this mortal frame. / . . .*

The whole translation tends to be eccentric, but it's splendid as poetry in its own right — never mind Virgil! [My edition was published by Pennsylvania State University in 1989, ISBN 0-271-00651-X].